# Get pwd EXPIRE_DATE

Tags: password, active-directory, passwd, sssd

I am trying to get EXPIRE_DATE of pwd for an active directory user in ubuntu.
I can get information about the user with lslogins user but no information about password expire dates that are set in AD.
and sudo chage -l user does not work: chage: user 'user' does not exist in /etc/passwd
is there something in realmd (sssd) that can give med such information?

Answer (score 1):

Using `net` (it will fail if the domain controller is not capable of returning the expiration date):

```
net ads user info {username}@{domain} -S {servername} -U {username}
```

or using `rpcclient` ([source](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2017-February/206345.html)) (`$USER` means current user):

```
RPCLOOKUPID=$(rpcclient -P -c "lookupnames $USER" dc1)
USERDCID=$(echo "$RPCLOOKUPID" | grep -e '[0-9]\{4,9\} ' -o)
QUERYUSER=$(rpcclient -P -c "queryuser $USERDCID" dc1)
EXPDATE=$(echo "$QUERYUSER" | grep 'Password must change Time' | cut -d > ":" -f 2,3,4,5 | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//')
```

Comment: Gratz. The date should be i.